# Catch block without arg

Tags: c#

I have a catch block like below:

```
catch (Exception e)
            {
                connection.Close();
                return null;
            }
```

I get a warning saying 'e' is not being used. I don't want to use it. But if I remove it I get an error saying "class type expected". What's to be done?

Comment: What type is connection? If it is IDisposable, you should consider a using block, which will automatically call Close (depending on the type) when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
catch
{ 
   connection.Close(); 
   return null; 
}
```

Comment: Non-CLS compliant exceptions are also catch by this notation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bb264489.aspx

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
try
{
     //code to throw exception
}
catch(ArgumentNullException)
{
    //do something in response to this exception
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //catch the general exception
}
```

this allows you to catch different types of exception without having to castch everything as with Danny's answer above (sorry i coulnd't just comment, not enough rating yet!)

Answer (score 0):

Take the `e` out